# equivalent to Telerik Html.Kendo().Grid(Model) in Tag Helper .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, telerik-grid, tag-helpers

I am migrating a code that has a grid binding to the view model `Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)`  I have the model already as a list of complex type with the @model property of the view
All I found while searching is how to add a datasource element with call to an action or ajax call to bind the data.  I don't want that. 
May be there is a way to bind the datasource to the view model.

Answer (score 0):

Tag Helper doesn't support local data binding. Would have been nice if Telerik took the 3 seconds to include that fact on their Datasource documentation.

https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-can-i-bind-data-use-taghelper